# jquery Slide up-down effect on "select" tag or combobox

Tags: jquery, animation, combobox

I have a "select" tag with the following options:

```
<select>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

I want to add the "slideUp" and "slideDown" effect using jquery but I can't find a simple example to approach my need. The effect should look like this combobox example: [Telerik Combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/configurator/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: That looks like a custom dropdown element. I don't think there is a way to customize the "native" `<select>` element...

Comment: Can this be approached using an unordered list?

Comment: If they can do it we can do it, I'm working on an a jQuery extentsion that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, you will need to play with the styling:

```js
$(function(){
    $.fn.extend({
        slidingSelect: function(options)
        {
            var select= $(this);
            var selector=select.selector;

            var selectedValue=select.val();

            if(selectedValue=="undefined")
                selectedValue=select.find("option:first").val();                

            var divToggle=$("<div>"+selectedValue+"</div>").attr({id:select.attr("id")+"Toggle"}).css({width:select.width()}).click(function(){
                $(selector).slideToggle();
            }).insertBefore(select);

            select.attr("size",6);  
            select.change(function(){
                divToggle.html(select.val());
                $(selector).slideToggle();
            });

        }       
    });
    $("#colors").hide().slidingSelect();

});
```

```css
div#colorsToggle
{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid black;

}

.select_style{
  position: absolute; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colors" class="select_style">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

This method extends jquery with a `slidingSelect` function, which creates a `toggle` div based upon the name of the select, and when that toggle div is clicked on the select `slidesDown` like it does in the Telerik Control.  You will style the `#{ID of Select}Toggle` in your CSS to create a better looking UI.

Comment: The solution is great, I've placed inside a panel above a datagrid and is pushing it down when the menu appears. How can I prevent this?

Comment: try `position:absolute` in the select style.

Comment: It works excellent!!! I edited your answer to add the select tag style (.select_style) so others can see the full solution. Thank you!!!

Comment: In case anyone want to use the "select" as a server control (runat="server") replace the following:  $("#colors").hide().slidingSelect();  whith this: $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_colors").hide().slidingSelect();

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is a select (option) hidden.
When I press the button, the select appears under the button.
When i choose any option, the button take the value chosen and the select disappears.

Hope your code will be share. :)